# python append to array in json object

Tags: python, arrays, json, append

I have the following json object in python:

```
jsonobj = {
          "a": {
              "b": {
                      "c": var1,
                      "d": var2,
                      "e": [],
                   },

                },
            }
```

And I would like to append key-value elements into "e", but can't figure out the syntax for it.  I tried appending with the following, but it doesn't come out right with the brackets and quotes:

```
jsobj["a"]["b"]["e"].append("'f':" + var3)
```

Instead, I want "e" to be the following:

```
"e":[
       {"f":var3, "g":var4, "h":var5},
       {"f":var6, "g":var7, "h":var8},
    ]
```

Does anyone know the right way to append to this json array? Much appreciation.

Comment: Technically speaking, this is not a JSON object (even though it's formatted in the JSON style), it's a python dict. It's not "coming out right with brackets and quotes" because you are `append()`ing a string to the dictionary value `[]`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
jsobj["a"]["b"]["e"].append({"f":var3, "g":var4, "h":var5})
jsobj["a"]["b"]["e"].append({"f":var6, "g":var7, "h":var8})
```

Answer (score 10):

Just add the dictionary as a dictionary object not a string :

```
jsobj["a"]["b"]["e"].append(dict(f=var3))
```

Full source :

```
var1 = 11
var2 = 32
jsonobj = {"a":{"b":{"c": var1,
                     "d": var2,
                     "e": [],
                    },
               },
           }
var3 = 444
jsonobj["a"]["b"]["e"].append(dict(f=var3))
```

jsonobj will contain :

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 11, 'd': 32, 'e': [{'f': 444}]}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jsonobj["a"]["b"]["e"] += [{'f': var3, 'g' : var4, 'h': var5}, 
                           {'f': var6, 'g' : var7, 'h': var8}]
```

Comment: There is [extend](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method for that.