# How do I append a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, file, append

How would I append a JSON file? I know how to append a JSON variable, but how do I append a file? for example, if my JSON file was:

```
{"people": [{"name" : "Michael Scott", "city": "Scranton"}]}
```

If I wanted to add another name to people, and that was in a JSON file, how would I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python append to array in json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895028/python-append-to-array-in-json-object)

Comment: load them first with `json.loads` (load from string) and then append the names. Then you can `json.dumps` (stringify) and rewrite the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
with open("json_exp.txt", "r+") as f:
         json_obj = json.loads(f.read())
         json_obj["people"].append({"name":"new_person"})
         f.seek(0)
         json.dump(json_obj, f)
```

This code will read a text file that have a JSON object in it and will append a new value to the dict that made by the JSON object in the file then it will store the new JSON object to the file.

Comment: what is f.seek?

Comment: To overwrite the old JSON object without it just append the new object

Comment: This is answering your question?

Comment: Let me test it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your destination json is:

```
# dest.json
{"people": [{"name" : "Michael Scott", "city": "Scranton"}]}
```

and you want to append the following json:

```
# source.json
{"name" : "Blah Blah", "city": "blah"}
```

Try:

```
import json

with open("destination.json") as fd, open("source.json") as fs:
    dest = json.load(fd)
    source = json.load(fs)
    dest["people"].append(source)
with open("destination.json", 'w') as fd:
    json.dump(dest, fd)
```